# NodeJS: Send HTTPS request but get HTTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am building a website using NodeJS, and I deploy it to Heroku. But when I open the website, something went wrong. Here is the problem:

Code:
In the main source file of my web:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = {
        rootURL: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('Host')}`,
    };

    res.render('home.html', data);
});
```

Then, in home.html, I include the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('{{rootURL}}'+'/about', {}, function(data){
        // Code here is deleted for now.
    }).fail(function(evt) {
        // Code here is deleted for now.
    });
</script>
```

Here I use hbs template, so {{rootURL}} is equal to the 'rootURL' property within the 'data' object rendered along with the 'home.html' page.
The '/about' is one of the APIs I designed for my web. It basically sends back something about the website itself and this information is wrapped in JSON.

Then, here comes the problem. The code works fine locally, and works well when I send HTTP request instead of HTTPS to Heroku. But if I send HTTPS request to Heroku, I'll get 'Mixed Content' Errors:
[Errors I get in Chrome Console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyqmA.png)

I then switched to 'Elements' tab in the developers tool, and I saw this:
[The schema is HTTP, not HTTPS!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ss1I.png)

I'm very confused here. I just grab the 'protocol'  property within the 'req' object, and fill in the template with it. So, I'm assuming if I enter **'[my-website-name].herokuapp.com' with 'https' schema** in my Chrome Browser, my nodeJS app deployed on Heroku should get 'https' for req.protocol. But Apparently it's not the case. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't actually have an SSL certificate? Heroku will be providing the HTTPS, but it will then translate it to normal HTTP internally when it hits your express endpoint, which is why it sees `req.protocol` as HTTP.

Is there any point in even providing the URL to `getJSON`? Why not just send it `$.getJSON('/about', callback)` and let the browser handle that?

Also, you haven't hidden your URL in that first image you uploaded, if that's what you were intending.

Comment: Thank you! Really Appreciate it! Yeah you're right. It doesn't make sense to use the full URL there. And the URL in the first image is not what I intended....

Answer (score 1):

Heroku router is doing SSL termination, so no matter if you connect via http or https, you get http on your side. Original protocol is however set in `X-Forward-Proto` header. You need use this value.